# has there ever been router virus able to send SMS (text)

Tags: malware, router, sms, firmware

I am fighting with my network provider.

If I have router with LTE GSM Card inside, is it possible for router malware to send text messages from it? Or has it ever been done? They say I subscribed to some paid services, which they allowed for unknown reasons.

I heard about using routers for DDoS attack or for reconaissance (Chameleon). Texting seems extremely challenging and hacker would probably go for easier target - mobile phones? Or maybe it would be easier to subscribe to paid services by spoofed SMS?

What operating system is there in TL-MR 3420? Busybox? Toybox? I found that you can install OpenWrt. What is there by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if your bill has truly unauthorized charges, then you are most likely the victim of [cramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramming_(fraud)).  If you didn't personally ask for the service, then you don't have to pay.  Have your service provider remove the charges.

Next, is it *technically* possible for a router to send a text message?  Yes.  Sending a text is easier than you think.  Basically, send an email to  `TargerPhoneNumber@ServiceProvider.com`.  Here are some examples.

```
AT&T: number@txt.att.net.
T-Mobile: number@tmomail.net.
Verizon: number@vtext.com.
Sprint: number@messaging.sprintpcs.com or number@pm.sprint.com.
Virgin Mobile: number@vmobl.com.
Tracfone: number@mmst5.tracfone.com.
Metro PCS: number@mymetropcs.com
```

So, sure... anything that can send an email can send a text.  That would include a router.  But! This isn't about technical feasibility.  This is about your ISP removing charges for services you didn't ask for.  AT&T was forced to pay $105 million for allowing third parties to cram fraudulent charges onto their customers bills in 2014.  Skip the technical wild goose chase and tell your network provider to reverse the charges.

Good luck!